# Rails partial not rendering HTML by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

What is it that makes Rails want to render `_post.json.erb` over `_post.html.erb` when I `render @post` from `show.html.erb`? My controller does `render :show`.

It works if I explicitly specify `render partial: 'post', formats: [:html]`, but why is that not the default?

The `request.format` from the controller reads `'text/html'`.

Comment: I think it depends on the first request's format, if it is JSON/JavaScript, it'll try to render the response as JS, same for HTML

Comment: Can you post your controller action and how the partial is referenced in the parent view?

Comment: sounds silly but may be you have a respond_to :json in the controller.

Comment: There is no `respond_to :json` in the controller. There is only `respond_to :html`.